# Page didn't redirect in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've created an authentication process with firebase and angularjs.

After the authentication process, the page must redirect to the `htmlnew.html` Using `$routeprovider`. But it doesn't redirect after authentication.

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="appName">
 <body>
 <div ng-controller="loginCtrl" id="message">
    <a ng-click="googleSignin()">SignIn into App</a>
 </div>
   <p id="load">Firebase SDK Loading&hellip;</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

**htmlnew.html**

```
<body>
<div id="message" ng-controller="loginpage">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <a ng-click="googleSignout()">Signout</a>
</div>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
 var app = angular.module("appName", ["ngRoute", "firebase"]);
 app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: 'public/index.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'public/htmlnew.html',
        controller: 'loginpage'
    })
  });

  app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope) {
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  $scope.googleSignin = function () {
  firebase.auth()
        .signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    var user = result.user;
    console.log(token);
    console.log(user);

  }).catch(function (error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log(errorCode);
    console.log(errorMessage);
    });
   }
 });

 app.controller('loginpage', function ($scope) {
 $scope.googleSignout = function () {
  firebase.auth().signOut()
        .then(function () {
            console.log('Signout Succesfull');
        }, function (error) {
            console.log('Signout Failed');
        });
   }
 });
```

**Project documentation**

[image]

For demo check on this Project [link](https://fierbaseproj.firebaseapp.com)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your demo has error in dev console `TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined` right after the page loads. Seems that `firebase` is not properly injected.

Comment: Sorry that's previous copy. Now deployed the project. Check it now.

Comment: Try below answers. May work

Answer (score 1):

Redirect to path using `$location`. Inject it in the controller dependencies and use as below

```
firebase.auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
        $location.path('/login');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For redirection after successfully signwithpopup u should provide state change in `function(result)` and if error it will catch in `function(error)`

**$location.path('/login);**

as you are using ngRoute. u can use `$location.path` for routing your state.

Hope this will help you.

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope,$location) {
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  $scope.googleSignin = function () {
  firebase.auth()
        .signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    var user = result.user;
    $location.path('/login');
    console.log(token);
    console.log(user);

  }).catch(function (error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log(errorCode);
    console.log(errorMessage);
    });
   }
 });
```

Comment: did u get your consoled token and user ? @PrasathV

Comment: Login complete and the page doesn't redirect to htmlnew.html. Checked in the console. `$$absUrl
:
"http://localhost:5000/#!/login"`

Comment: Yes. Token:ya29.GlxiBL5ICWFYMX3DC8eQ_Phl1vuev1LP-6iaelDUfQFtSqTUmi4Mj3o1EgAcv4czW53jEvuIjICRL3i5MkjOibjGs0B69u2lP9kaqnerI25lk0E5pdYRtHifXL3oVw...

Comment: when u logged in. did your url changed  to /login ? @PrasathV

Comment: Nope. Didn't change to /login @Himesh Suthar

Comment: u injected $location in controller. and you put $location.path("/login");  not working.. try template: <h1>Hello</h1>  instead of templateurl and check it

Comment: Tried as u said it doesn't display the h1 element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146056/discussion-between-himesh-suthar-and-prasath-v).

Answer (score 1):

```
firebase.auth()
        .signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {

    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    var user = result.user;

     // You missed this $location.path('/pathYouNeed ');
```